# Tools for parsing nginx/apache access logs for malicious traffic

Tags: apache, nginx

What are some tools for monitoring our access logs for malicious traffic? Paid or open source, it doesn't really matter.

We're hosting a number of sites on both apache and nginx. Some of these sites got infected with malware and we have a hard time finding out the initial successful vector of attack.

I can find some tools that can act on malicious requests (fail2ban for example) but I have a hard time identifying tools which enable us to manually review traffic and identify potential malicious requests.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a tool exactly, but below is a small python script that I run in Jupyter for same purpose. It uses the [lars](https://lars.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for parsing nginx logs. You can use it to browse/query your logs and identify what you would consider malicious/suspicious. Then see where it's coming from in case you wish to ban. The output looks like

[image: dataframe head]

```
import httpx
import gzip
import lars.dns
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

from pathlib import Path
from lars import csv
from lars.apache import ApacheSource, COMBINED


localdir = 'path to your nginx logs'
localpath = Path(localdir)

def decompress(infile, tofile):
    with open(infile, 'rb') as inf, open(tofile, 'w', encoding='utf8') as tof:
        decom_str = gzip.decompress(inf.read()).decode('utf-8')
        tof.write(decom_str)

# Change this if your access logs are named differently
all_access_gz = list(localpath.glob('access.log.*.gz'))
all_access_gz = [x.as_posix() for x in all_access_gz]

# Unzip them all
for f in all_access_gz:
    decompress(f, f.removesuffix('.gz'))

# Delete the .gz files
for f in all_access_gz:
    os.remove(f)


access_logs = list(localpath.glob('*access.*'))
access_logs = [x.as_posix() for x in access_logs]

access_csvfile = localdir + '/all_accss.csv'
with open(access_csvfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    for f in access_logs:
        with open(f) as infile:
            with ApacheSource(infile, log_format=COMBINED) as source, csv.CSVTarget(outfile) as target:
                for row in source:
                    target.write(row)

cols = ['remote_ip', 'dash_empty','remote_user', 'date_time', 'request', 'status', 'bytes_sent', 'http_referer', 'user_agent', 'gzip_ratio']
ndf = pd.read_csv(access_csvfile, names = cols, index_col = False )

# Keep only columns you need
ndf = ndf[['remote_ip', 'date_time', 'request', 'bytes_sent', 'status']]
ndf['date_time'] = ndf['date_time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
ndf.head()


# Put your own "suspicious thing to look for" here, this is just one example:
hacker = ndf[ndf['request'].str.contains("php", case = False)]

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
url_base = 'https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/'

ncc = []
addr = []

# Look up the ncc
with httpx.Client() as c:
    for idx, row in hacker.iterrows():
        url = url_base + row['remote_ip']
        res = c.get(url, headers=headers)
        smth = res.json().get('entities')[0].get('vcardArray')[1]
        n = smth[1][3]
        a = smth[2][1].get('label')
        a = a.replace('\n', ',')
        ncc.append(n)
        addr.append(a)
hacker['ncc'] = ncc
hacker['addr'] = addr
```